# SQL AVG statement another table

Tags: sql, average

I'm having trouble with a SQL query. The goal is to see only the certain entries on a specific date (I got this already) which have an average score below 1 in their last 5 home games.

You can see the tables here: 
http://dbup2date.uni-bayreuth.de/downloads/bundesliga/Klassendiagramm_Bundesliga.pdf

I have this code so far:

```
SELECT 
    A.Spieltag, A.Datum, A.Uhrzeit, B.Name AS Heim 
FROM 
    Spiel AS A 
JOIN 
    Verein AS B ON A.Heim = B.V_ID AND B.Liga = 1
WHERE 
    Spieltag = 5 
HAVING 
    AVG(SELECT Tore_Heim 
        FROM Spiel AS A 
        JOIN Verein AS B 
        WHEN A.Heim = B.V_ID) < 1
```

Sorry for my bad English

Thank you

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you group by any =fields that you are not aggregating on when you use HAVING. And you can simplify that HAVING clause since you are already referencing those exact tables in your FROM:

```
SELECT 
    A.Spieltag, A.Datum, A.Uhrzeit, B.Name AS Heim 
FROM 
    Spiel AS A 
JOIN 
    Verein AS B ON A.Heim = B.V_ID AND B.Liga = 1
WHERE 
    Spieltag = 5 
GROUP BY A.Spieltag, A.Datum, A.Uhrzeit, B.Name
HAVING 
    AVG(Tore_Heim) < 1
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for that, but can you tell me how to Choose the average only of the last 5 home games? because like it is right now it is of all home games i think?

Comment: I would, but your field names are all in German. I don't know what to filter on.